# Update query not working properly in servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, sql-update

Hi all when I try to update any record in the database it shows successfully updated however when I check the database it is not yet updated.

There is no error in the code but it is not working. Can anyone look into this and point out the problem in the code.

I am trying to update the username using the phone number as an unique value.

Thank you.

**Updatelogin.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action ="update" method="post">
       phone : <input type ="text" name ="phone" /> </br> 
 Username : <input type ="text" name ="uname"/> </br>


<input type ="submit" value = "update">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Update.java***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class update
 */
@WebServlet("/update")
public class update extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public update() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws IOException,ServletException{
                processRequset (request,response);
            }

            public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                processRequset (request,response);
            }

            public void processRequset(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws IOException,ServletException{
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

                String phone =request.getParameter("phone");
                String username =request.getParameter("uname");

                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        try {




            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/register","root","toor");  

            PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(  
            "update headwy set uname =? where phone=?"); 
             pstmt.setString(1,phone);
             pstmt.setString(2,username);


             pstmt.executeUpdate();  

            out.print("You are successfully update...");  
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();

        }
          catch (Exception e2) {System.out.println(e2);
           }  
            }
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Actually, auto commit is usually set to true by default (I think), so the OP probably should not have to call `commit()`.  But other than this, I can think of no reason why the update would not throw an exception, but the data does not show up.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you set Preparedstatement argument wrongly

```
pstmt.setString(1,phone);
pstmt.setString(2,username);
```

it should be

```
pstmt.setString(1,username);
pstmt.setString(2,phone);
```

Check your query "update headwy set uname =? where phone=?");

Answer (score 2):

You are missing order of the parameters in your query 1st parameter requires username value and 2nd parameter requires phone number value. So, change order of parameters it will works

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(  
            "update headwy set uname =? where phone=?"); 
             pstmt.setString(1,username);
             pstmt.setString(2,phone);
```